# Issue installing pip and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install Pandas with Pip and am running into some strange issues.  Command prompt reported that pip is an unrecognized command.  I thought that was strange, but decided to definitively remedy that by installing pip with the following commands:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

I received the report that an existing version of pip was found, uninstalled, and the new version was installed.  I then proceeded to run

```
pip install pandas
```

And I was informed that `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I then added to the path environment and the issue is still persisting.  It's worth noting that I installed Python 3.6 by installing Anaconda.  What am I missing here?[image]

Comment: If you are using anaconda open up the anaconda prompt and use conda install pandas

Comment: pip is likely not in your path, and therefore windows is unable to discover it.

Comment: pip is usually in the scripts directory under python.  For me that is: "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe"

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you should be looking for `pip3` rather than `pip`.

Answer (score 2):

The `pip` command is not found because it's not in your path.

You should add the following to your `PATH` environment variable:

```
;%PYTHON_HOME%\;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\
```

A simple Google search should help you find how to change environment variables for you version of Windows.

For example, see [this page from the Java documentation](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Comment: as mentioned earlier it is in my path environment variable.  I have ensured this.  I was able to install using conda in the anaconda prompt

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
C:\Users\Username>cd C:\Python27\Scripts

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip freeze
```

If you're using a different Python version, replace Python27, with your version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use `!pip install pandas` in your Python program without having to open the windows/anaconda prompt.

But as others said, pip is not in your active directory and you would have to open the anaconda prompt or go to the library where pip is installed